# Using Hyperledger Fabric REST interface in multi-organization network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to set up a 3-organization network, with users of each org connecting to their own peer over a REST interface.

In the examples I've seen for single-org networks, the rest connection is made to localhost, i.e. the host of all the Docker containers. In a multi-org network, what should I be trying to connect the REST interface to from the client, is it the peer of that org, i.e. peer0.org1 etc?